# gcc include_next cannot resolve next same name header, but it's there down the dir list

Tags: gcc

When compiling qt from source, #include_next cannot resolve next same name header, but it's in there down the dir list,
in the wrapper header it calls #include_next <stdint.h> which failed.

Well I think most of the information lays below.

```
$ cmake --build . --parallel
...
/usr/bin/c++ --sysroot=/home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13 -DHAVE_ATEXIT -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DHAVE_OT -DHAVE_PTHREAD -DHAVE_SCHED_H -DHAVE_SCHED_Y
IELD -DHB_EXTERN="" -DHB_NDEBUG -DHB_NO_UNICODE_FUNCS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_JAVA_STYLE_ITERATORS -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CO
NVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_VERSION_TAGGING -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/
3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/include/harfbuzz -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/src/corelib/Core_autogen/include -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qt
base/include -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/include/QtCore -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/corelib -I/data/.gccb/qt
6.3.2-build/qtbase/src/corelib -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/src/corelib/global -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/src/corelib/kern
el -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/corelib/../3rdparty/tinycbor/src -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/include/QtCore/6
.3.2 -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/include/QtCore/6.3.2/QtCore -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/corelib/../3rdparty
/double-conversion/double-conversion -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/corelib/../3rdparty/double-conversion -I/data/.gcc
b/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/corelib/../3rdparty/forkfd -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/src/corelib/.rcc -I/data/.gccb/qt-eve
rywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/include/QtZlib -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbas
e/src/3rdparty/zlib -I/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build/qtbase/src/3rdparty/zlib -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/pcre2
/src -I/data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng -DNDEBUG -Os -std=c++17 -flto -fno-fat-lto-objects -fPIC -fvi
sibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -w -fno-exceptions -Wsuggest-override -pthread -MD -MT qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMake
Files/BundledHarfbuzz.dir/src/hb-blob.cc.o -MF qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMakeFiles/BundledHarfbuzz.dir/src/hb-blob.cc.o.d -o qtba
se/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/CMakeFiles/BundledHarfbuzz.dir/src/hb-blob.cc.o -c /data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/h
arfbuzz-ng/src/hb-blob.cc
In file included from /data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb-common.h:69,
                 from /data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb-blob.h:34,
                 from /data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb.h:31,
                 from /data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb.hh:176,
                 from /data/.gccb/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.2/qtbase/src/3rdparty/harfbuzz-ng/src/hb-blob.cc:28:
/home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
    9 | # include_next <stdint.h>
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

michael@michael-GW-001M1A-FTF:/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build$ ls -l /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/include/
stdint.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 michael michael 328 Oct 27 15:19 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/include/stdint.h

michael@michael-GW-001M1A-FTF:/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build$ echo | c++ -xc++ -E -Wp,-v -                                               
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/aarch64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/../../../../include/c++/9.5.0
 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/../../../../include/c++/9.5.0/aarch64-linux-gnu
 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/../../../../include/c++/9.5.0/backward
 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/include
 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu           vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
 /usr/include                 <<<!!! HERE we have the stdint.h file WHY failure? !!!>>>
End of search list.                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
michael@michael-GW-001M1A-FTF:/data/.gccb/qt6.3.2-build$ ll /usr/include/stdint.h /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux
-gnu/9.5.0/include/stdint.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 michael michael  328 Oct 27 15:19 /home/michael/.gccb/gcc-13/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/9.5.0/include/stdint.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root      8094 Dec 25  2020 /usr/include/stdint.h
```

as @n.m. chould be an AI commented, it's because I set sysroot.
If I don't set sysroot it fails with `/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.28' not found`

The libstdc++.so.6 in use is not from my custom gcc sysroot from which it should be. What is the recommended way to solve this?

Comment: You set sysroot. gcc will not look in /usr/include/ but in $sysroot/usr/include/.

Comment: If you want to build a program with a newer version of gcc/g++, you should run that version of gcc/g++, not set sysroot to anywhere.

Comment: Thanks but not a different version, from /usr/bin gcc|c++ everything's just a symbol to 9.5.0

Comment: Did you install 9.5.0 yourself from the source? What exactly fails when you don't set sysroot, the build or execution of the built program?

Comment: build qt from source failed. @n. m. ; with compiler gcc-9.5.0 which was built from source.